# request location permission in android marshmallow and previous version

Tags: android, android-permissions

I was reading the thread:
[Android Marshmallow Location Permission handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871432/android-marshmallow-location-permission-handling)
And now, I can handle the location and some other permissions in android API 23, but, how I can know if the previous android versions have the location permission enable?

Comment: There is no runtime permission model on pre marshmallow devices. The only thing that was done is the AppOpsManager. Usually, your permissions are granted on pre MarshMallow by default if you added them to manifest.

Comment: found a thread about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921136/how-to-check-if-android-permission-package-usage-stats-permission-is-given

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468